# Upsert for combination of foreign keys which are not primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table as follows:

```
mytable (
  id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  user_id int unsigned not null,
  program_id int unsigned not null,
  description varchar(255),
  foreign key (user_id) references user(id),
  foreign key (program_id) references program(id)
)
```

What I am wanting to do:

- I want the `user_id`/`program_id` combination to be unique.
- If someone tries to add a new description into `mytable` for the same user_id/program_id I want the current row to be updated rather than inserted as a new row.

I am familiar with how to use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for a basic primary key.  What do I need to do to get it to work with duplicate composite foreign keys when they are not primary keys?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a composite `UNIQUE` constraint as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD UNIQUE `my_composite_index`(`user_id`, `program_id`);
```

That will work as expected with the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax, as explained in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If you specify an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value **in a `UNIQUE` index** or `PRIMARY KEY`, an `UPDATE` of the old row occurs.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`user_id`, `program_id`, `description`) 
    VALUES(1, 2, 'my description')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `description` = 'my description'
```